# Find the coordinates of the center of mass of a homogeneous body

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the coordinates of the center of mass of a homogeneous body bounded by surfaces $y = x^2 + z^2$, $x^2 + z^2 = 10$, $y = 0$. I don't understand how to set the limits of integration.